# Prime gaps from the Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

More specifically: Is there a closed-form or recursive expression, or some other algorithm, for finding the *largest* gap available for a given iteration of the sieve?

We'll look at the wheel sieves created for each "layer" of sieve, labeling them $W_2, W_3$, etc. We can write the first few out without trouble:

$$\begin{align}
W_2 &= \{1\} \\
W_3 &= \{1,5\} \\
W_5 &= \{1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29\}
\end{align}$$

As we use more primes for the wheels, they become larger than can be easily found by hand: $W_7$ has $48$ elements below $210$, and $W_{11}$ has $480$ elements below $2310$. Even calculating these by brute force computation takes a bit of time.

We can ask, what is the maximum gap, $\hat{g}(p)$, that can be formed by $W_p$?
For $W_2$ to $W_{11}$, it's easy to determine this sequence is $\hat{g}(p) = 2,4,6,10,14$.

Since $W_{p_i}$ is valid up to $n = p^2_{i+1}$, we can say that $\hat{g}(p)$ is the largest prime gap *possible* among primes less than $n$, other than the largest prime below $n$. This series is $3,7,23,113,113,1129,1329$, and we can see that past $\hat{g}(11) = 14$ at $p = 113$, the first-occurence primes become much larger than $p_{i+1}^2$.

The question, then, is this: is there a closed-form or iterative expression for these maximal gaps? Or are they fundamentally only determined by brute force?

Note: A bit of extra research (after I started writing) suggests that this sequence is the Jacobsthal function on the primorials ([OEIS A048670](https://oeis.org/A048670)). So I'll do some research into that as well.

Comment: Did you try OEIS?

Comment: @markvs Yes; I linked the OEIS sequence at the end of the text. No closed-form formula there, but wondering if anyone knows of more recent publications.

Comment: Then you should contact the authors of the papers referred to in OEIS, and ask them. For example, T. Tao is listed there. Or you can just google or search the arXiv.